# Trying to solve maze using depth-first search algorithm, but does not print the right coordinates

Tags: c, maze

I am trying to search for the starting position of the maze by looping through the maze.txt. For that, in my stack ADT, I passed all of my functions three arguments, the stack, the x position and the y position, I tried testing the stack ADT using simple values and it seems to push nodes and pop nodes pretty well, however when I try it on the maze, it doesn't seem to be obtaining the right coordinates for the starting position. This is how I have implemented it to obtain the starting position. (I am using my linked list ADT in my stack ADT and I have create x pos and y pos in my stack struct)

I am using the depth-first search algorithm in a non-recursive way to solve the maze. As of now, I am really lost on how to approach this, I've searched everywhere, but I have yet to find a non-recursive algorithm. For now, I am planning on searching through every single direction and pushing and pop depending on if the move is valid or not. I would really like to improve myself as a programmer and would like to understand thoroughly on how to solve the maze so if in the future if I encounter something like this I can solve it using the best techniques out there which take less time.

```
void mazeSolution(char**maze)
{
    stack*currentCell;
    int i;
    int j;

    i=0;
    j=0;

    currentCell = create();

    while(maze[i][j] == 'F')
    {
       if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
       {
          currentCell->xpos = i;

          currentCell->ypos = j;

         push(currentCell,currentCell->xpos,currentCell->ypos);
       }
    }

    printStack(currentCell);
}

void printList(node*theList)
{
    node*currentPosition;

    currentPosition = theList;

    while(currentPosition != NULL)
    {
        printf("This is the value of the current node : %d, %d\n",currentPosition->xpos, currentPosition->ypos);
        currentPosition= currentPosition->next;
    }
}


void printStack(stack*theStack)
{
    printList(theStack->list);

}
```

I actually noticed something, without the create() and if I comment out the entire while loop, if I just called the printStack(); it will still print 0,0 so that means that there is something wrong with the way I have printed or the way I am pushing the node. However, I don't understand why it works perfectly fine when I test with a bunch of values...not with maze

Comment: How do the apparent coordinates for the starting position differ from what you expect?

Comment: The actual coordinates are 1,0 and this is printing out 0,0

Comment: You've set `i` and `j` to zero and not modified them. Perhaps that is why you get (0, 0)?

Comment: I was thinking about that earlier, but if I take the initializations out, I get a compiler error saying "src/mazegen.c:20:15: warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
               ^
src/mazegen.c:20:18: warning: ‘j’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
                  ^
src/mazegen.c:22:29: warning: ‘currentCell’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
           currentCell->xpos = i;

Comment: Have you thought about iterating over the `maze` array with a couple of `for` loops, one for the x-direction and one for the y-direction?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that now, however it is still printing out 0,0

Comment: In the `MazeSolution` function, the code never ***changes*** `i` and `j`. The function will do nothing unless you add code to ***change*** `i` and `j`.

Comment: so for instance, increment i or j when the start position is encountered. ??

Comment: Do you even know the recursive algorithm? All you are doing here is using a stack to simulate what a recursive call would do. The algorithm is the same.

Comment: Yes, I do know what a recursive algorithm is and I completely understand what you are saying, my problem right now is my function.It is not obtaining the correct coordinates for the x and y positions.